# How to merge audio and video .webm files into one in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-processing, webm

I have two files (audio & video) that have have been output after recording. I am trying to merge them in node JS with no success.

Can someone please guide me, How I merge audio and video .webm files.

Below is the sample code that I am trying with.

```
var util = require("util");
var child_process = require("child_process");
var exec = child_process.exec;

const audioFile =
  "./RMa56600d802119433a6fcd59b5404ff49_works/MT56a3ad9dfad21408331fb93b2205061d/1.webm";
const videoFile =
  "./RMa56600d802119433a6fcd59b5404ff49_works/MTf4a4283fa27c7f6193749f39462fdeec/1.webm";
const outputFileName = "./RMa56600d802119433a6fcd59b5404ff49_works/merged.webm";

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log("Puts func called");
  stdout ? util.print("stdout: " + stdout) : null;
  stderr ? util.print("stderr: " + stderr) : null;
  error ? console.log("exec error: " + error) : null;
}


exec("ffmpeg -i videoFile -i audioFile -map 0:0 -map 1:0 outputFileName", puts);
```

Below is the error that I get.

> app.js:237 Uncaught TypeError: exec is not a function

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I currently do this successfully with webm/opus and mp4/mp4a files in one of my projects. To achieve the desired outcome the ffmpeg command I use looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i vfn -i afn -vcodec copy -acodec copy ofn
```

but I use:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;

const output = spawn('ffmpeg',['-i',vfn,'-i',afn,'-vcodec','copy','-acodec','copy',ofn]);
```

where vfn, afn and ofn are the video, audio and output filenames.  I use this in a forked process so synchronous blocking is not an issue. The ffmpeg copy operation is very fast anyway.